# wkwebview requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback not working

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

i have a `wkwebview` that goes into youtube and I would like to click on a video without it automatically throwing me into the video player.

I tried stopping this in 3 different ways

1. using the `config.requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback = true`
2. in the `decidePolicyForNavigationAction` delegate function i check for the presence of a youtube video and set `decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.Cancel)`
3. i also added a `webView.stopLoading()` to the stuff i did in #2

despite doing that, clicking on the link still triggers the video to automatically start playing.

i'm out of ideas; any thoughts?

i know i could try injecting some javascript but that seems like a last resort to me.

Comment: Same here... I am on iOS10 with Swift 3, according to the apple documents, it should work. I just filed a bug on the WebKit bug report website.

Comment: hmm actually, please track the issue here: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=162329, no progress so far.